# Book recommendation for IMC (International Mathematical Olympiad)

Tags: contest-math, book-recommendation

I'm a novice math contester. Looking for recommendation for a good book for the IMC competition (International Mathematical Olympiad, A competition for undergraduates).

Heard good things about "Problem solving through problem" by Larson, do you recommend it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://chiuchang.org/imc/en/category/saimc-2019/ I presume you mean this IMC correct?

Comment: No, I think OP means [this one](https://www.imc-math.org.uk/)

Comment: E.Nole is correct!
Its an undergraduate competition

Comment: Have a look at *Putnam and beyond*.